# How Google URLs format applied to php application?

Tags: php, html, url, curl

In many php websites URLs is written as `page.php?id=123` or `rewrite moded page/Id/123`

But is google I noticed that URLs is like `google.com/search?q=Wordpress`

I try to format website links to be similar but I didn't succeed even with rewrite rules

Also I found websites use same URLs formatting 
Torrentz2.eu

How to apply this type of links in php application?

Comment: Google actually uses the format: google.com/search?q=Wordpress

Comment: What's the question? Are you trying to create URLs without the `.php` extension as in `/search` or are you having trouble reading the query as in `?id=123`?

Comment: Hide .php result example.com/search/Wordpress but the link above is queried one.  Search?=Wordpress      In php  GET function will get the value after search=Wordpress witch is Wordpress but have nothing to do with URLs structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to save slug for each record.

for example

title of a product: A4Tech Mouse

slug : a4tec-mouse

so you can set url

example.com/searc?q=a4tech-mouse

and set htaccess rule for above url

Comment: You mean rewrite rule for link if you have straight forward examples would you please share it